# What should I do know to know the frequency from complex signal?

Tags: dft

Now I'm trying to digging the DFT function.
But nobody tell about the what do we need it at least to solve the dft from the complex signal- a signal with many frequencies

If I got the complex signal as the below,

[image]

then what should we have to know at the first time to do DFT?
Especially, What kind of things should I have to know to solve a signal with many frequencies?

I've seen some parameter from example as the below when I googling.
sampling rate, N, nyquist rate, ..., sort of things.
In the practically field for engineer, if they got a that kind signal, how do they do at the first time?

as I know the below image is DFT equation.
[image]

then how do we decide the "N" and "m"?

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE!  Why do you say the signal is complex? Do you mean complicated? Here, "complex" means having real and imaginary components.

Comment: @PeterK. sorry I give you some misunderstanding. yes exactly your are right. I mean that is a signal with many frequencies.

Comment: capital $N$ is the number of values your signal has (the length of $x(n)$), lowercase $n$ is just the variable, used in the summation to solve for $X(m)$.

Comment: @goldrik As you know the real world's signal is continuous not discrete. so we need to discrete it from continuous signal. but I don't know how do we decide length of signal?

Comment: Yes, if you're starting with a continuous signal, then it should be discretized before applying the DFT. However, the number of samples you use is entirely up to you; this decision will not change the way you apply the transform (of course, you should follow the Nyquist Sampling Theorem when discretizing, but that's a different problem). I do believe your example signal is already discretized, since there is clearly a value at each time step (the plot just connects the points).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say "complex" signal, I assume you mean just a signal with many frequencies, and not a "complex-valued" signal, in which the the signal values themselves are complex numbers. Let me know if I am incorrect in this assumption. (Actually, computation of DFT is the same in either case).

I'm also assuming your signal is discrete.

The discrete Fourier Transform, $F(\omega)$, can be found by solving the following equation (where N is the number of samples your signal, $f[n]$, contains)

$$F(\omega) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} f[n] e^{\frac{-j 2\pi \omega n}{N}}$$

Alternatively, you could use the function `fft()` on MATLAB.

Comment: sorry I give you some misunderstanding. yes exactly your are right. I mean that is a signal with many frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

*In the practically field for engineer*, you should at least get into a summary of all signal processing concepts you have mentioned.

As an example, sample frequency refers to the frequency at which your are obtaining a sample from an continuous signal (i.e Electric signal from a sensor).